# bat file - launch and then minimize edge in windows10

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have made a small bat file that runs a specific web page in edge.
However, I would like to start edge minimized

I have tried:

```
start /B  microsoft-edge:"http://www.dr.dk/radio/live/p4kbh" /MIN

start /MIN /B  microsoft-edge:"http://www.dr.dk/radio/live/p4kbh"
```

Both launches the web page correctly but does not minimize the page.
My guess is that I need to minimize it after it is launched.
But how do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `start "" /MIN ...` (no `/B`)?

Comment: Has been tried, but no luck :-)

Comment: I don't believe these arguments work for Universal Applications, such as Microsoft Edge, Calculator, etc. I'm an engineer on the Edge team, and have submitted a ticket to consider adding support for command-line arguments to Edge; I'll see to it that I mention this scenario for consideration as well. Can I ask why you would like to start minimized? What is your scenario?

Comment: I'm opening a live-radio page that just need to play its music in the background. So to avoid edge taking over from my current tasks, it should be minimized

Comment: Voting to close this as *not programming related*, since this is more of a Super User or Server Fault request. That being said, I also provided an answer below that I feel is the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Edge, and other Universal Apps, do not presently support the classic `/min` argument. For now, your best option is to use another local browser, such as Internet Explorer:

```
> start /min iexplore http://radio.com
```